# Stripe is not defined (ember-cli)

Tags: ember.js, stripe-payments, ember-cli

I've seen two separate users, both Windows 7 and Firefox 34, have a `Stripe is not defined` error with my Stripe initializer.

I use `.setPublishableKey()` to take the key from my `ENV`, like so:

```
initializer =
  name: 'stripe'
  initialize: ->
    Stripe.setPublishableKey(ENV.STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY)

`export default initializer`
```

I include the Stripe JS like so:

```
<html>
  <head>
    {{content-for 'head'}}

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
```

What could be causing this? And how could I fix it?

I know I could simply check to see if Stripe is defined before setting the publishable key, but that's likely not sufficient to get users to use the Stripe-related functionality.

Comment: Where is your ember app defined?  In the {{content-for 'head'}}?

Comment: @Kingpin2k within the `<body>`. It's a pretty typical `ember-cli` app.

Comment: While vendoring the file would almost definitely work, with Stripe.js that'd put you within scope for a different level of PCI compliance. So I'd heavily recommend not doing that.

Comment: Good point, wasn't aware of that at all.

Comment: I'm going to assume that it isn't reproducible and they didn't have the dev tools open to show that the file failed to download.  That'd be the most likely scenario

Comment: @AlexSexton suggested what I think could be a similar scenario, which is they had external scripts blocked. Given that the majority of my traffic is coming from Reddit, I find that much likelier. I wonder if there's a reasonable way to handle that scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Josh, it seems it's the way the `ember-stripe-service` package is initialized.

Offending line: https://github.com/ride/ember-stripe-service/blob/master/app/initializers/stripe-service.js#L15

There's a workaround mentioned in this comment: https://github.com/ride/ember-stripe-service/issues/12#issuecomment-94524196

I had your issue and the fix in the comment above worked well. Here's my version in Coffeescript

`app/initializers/fake-stripe.coffee`

```
`import config from '../config/environment'`

initialize = (container, application) ->
  if (config.environment != 'test')
    return
  if (typeof Stripe != 'undefined')
    return

  window.Stripe =
    setPublishableKey: ->
    card: createToken: ->

StripeInitializer =
  name: 'fake-stripe'
  before: 'stripe'
  initialize: initialize

`export {initialize}`
`export default StripeInitializer`
```